# Ajax combine Associative Array with Form Serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I'm trying to ajax over data that is spread across some javascript code with and a form.

Currently I have an Associative array with my data in it:

```
var AjaxSendData = {};
AjaxSendData['t_searchtext'] = searchtext;
AjaxSendData['t_numofres'] = numofres;
AjaxSendData['t_orderbydesc'] = orderbydesc;
AjaxSendData['t_columnnum'] = columnnum;
AjaxSendData['t_pagenum'] = pageNum;
AjaxSendData['t_contenttype'] = contenttype;
AjaxSendData['t_MediaFilterType'] = MediaTypeID;
AjaxSendData['t_status'] = status;
AjaxSendData['t_ResultsFilterID'] = ResultsFilterID;
AjaxSendData['t_FilterIdType'] = FilterIdType;
```

Additionally I have a form I need to serialize with this id #addionalargs.

This form contains multiple values including lists made from checkboxes.  That need to be serialized as well.

I'm using Mvc so I would like the model binder to still be able to bind the values for validation purposes and cleaner code.

Does anybody know how I can combine the data between the Associative Array and the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize your form to JavaScript object (associative array) this isn't built in that I know of so here is a function for it.

```
function SerializeObject(a) {
var o = {};        
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
```

}

then you need to extend AjaxSendData:

```
    var AddArgs = $('#yourform').serializeArray();

    var AdditionalArgs = SerializeObject(AddArgs)

    $.extend(AjaxSendData, AdditionalArgs);
```